# How to return multiple rows in a LEFT JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, amfphp

I have a situation where lets say i'm trying to get the information about some food. Then I need to display all the information plus all the ingredients in that food.

With my query, i'm getting all the information in an array but only the first ingredient...

```
   myFoodsArr = 
        [0]
          foodDescription = "the description text will be here"
          ratingAverage = 0
          foodId = 4
          ingredient = 1
          ingAmount = 2
          foodName = "Awesome Food name"
          typeOfFood = 6
          votes = 0
```

I would like to get something back like this...

```
        myFoodsArr = 
            [0]
              foodDescription = "the description text will be here"
              ratingAverage = 0
              foodId = 4
              ingArr = {ingredient: 1, ingAmount: 4}, {ingredient: 3, ingAmount: 2}, {ingredient: 5, ingAmount: 1}
              foodName = "Awesome Food name"
              typeOfFood = 6
              votes = 0
```

This is the query im working with right now. How can I adjust this to return the food ID 4 and then also get ALL the ingredients for that food? All while at the same time doing other things like getting the average rating of that food?

Thanks!

```
   SELECT a.foodId, a.foodName, a.foodDescription, a.typeOfFood, c.ingredient, c.ingAmount, AVG(b.foodRating) AS ratingAverage, COUNT(b.foodId) as tvotes 
FROM `foods` a 
LEFT JOIN `foods_ratings` b 
   ON a.foodId = b.foodId 
LEFT JOIN `foods_ing` c 
   ON a.foodId=c.foodId 
WHERE a.foodId=4
```

**EDIT:**

Catcall introduced this concept of "sub queries" I never heard of, so I'm trying to make that work to see if i can do this in 1 query easily. But i just keep getting a return false. This is what I was trying with no luck..

```
//I changed some of the column names to help them be more distinct in this example

SELECT a.foodId, a.foodName, a.foodDescription, a.typeOfFood, AVG(b.foodRating) AS ratingAverage, COUNT(b.foodId) as tvotes 
FROM foods a 
LEFT JOIN foods_ratings b ON a.foodId = b.foodId 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT fId, ingredientId, ingAmount 
                 FROM foods_ing 
                 WHERE fId = 4 
                 GROUP BY fId) c ON a.foodId = c.fId 
           WHERE a.foodId = 4";
```

**EDIT 1 more thing related to ROLANDS GROUP_CONCAT/JSON Idea as a solution 4 this**

I'm trying to make sure the JSON string im sending back to my Flash project is ready to be properly parsed `Invalid JSON parse input.` keeps popping up..

so im thinking i need to properly have all the double quotes in the right places.

But in my MySQL query string, im trying to escape the double quotes, but then it makes my mySQL vars not work, for example...

If i do this..

```
GROUP_CONCAT('{\"ingredient\":', \"c.ingredient\", ',\"ingAmount\":', \"c.ingAmount\", '}')`
```

I get this...

`{"ingredient":c.ingredient,"ingAmount":c.ingAmount},{"ingredient":c.ingredient,"ingAmount":c.ingAmount},{"ingredient":c.ingredient,"ingAmount":c.ingAmount}`

How can i use all the double quotes to make the JSON properly formed without breaking the mysql?

Comment: You should copy and paste actual SQL DDL for your tables. As it is, the odds are that the query you posted won't return anything at all besides an error message. ("foodId" isn't the same as "foodsId".)

Comment: Looks like you got your quotes messed up. The text c.ingredient is now fed to mysql as a string - that's not good, Mysql should interpret that as a column reference. You'll want the SQL to look like I showed you in my answer, and you need to make sure to embed this correctly in a PHP string. Take a look at the PHP string syntax. http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: In your first edit, where you say "concept of subqueries", you changed column names to what appear to be names that don't exist in your tables. (Original query referred to foods_ing.foodId; edited query refers to foods_ing.fid.) Columns that don't exist won't ever work.

Comment: @catcall fyi I noted that I changed the column names in this example to help illustrait the idea better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT    food_ingredients.foodId
,         food_ingredients.foodName
,         food_ingredients.foodDescription
,         food_ingredients.typeOfFood
,         food_ingredients.ingredients
,         AVG(food_ratings.food_rating) food_rating
,         COUNT(food_ratings.foodId)    number_of_votes 
FROM      (
           SELECT    a.foodId
           ,         a.foodName
           ,         a.foodDescription
           ,         a.typeOfFood
           ,         GROUP_CONCAT(
                         '{ingredient:', c.ingredient,
                     ,   ',ingAmount:', c.ingAmount, '}'
                     ) ingredients
           FROM      foods a 
           LEFT JOIN foods_ing c 
           ON        a.foodsId = c.foodsId 
           WHERE     a.foodsId=4
           GROUP BY  a.foodId
          ) food_ingredients
LEFT JOIN food_ratings
ON        food_ingredients.foodId = food_ratings.foodId
GROUP BY  food_ingredients.foodId
```

Note that the type of query you want to do is not trivial in any SQL-based database.

The main problem is that you have one master (food) with two details (ingredients and ratings). Because those details are not related to each other (other than to the master) they form a cartesian product with each other (bound only by their relationship to the master).

The query above solves that by doing it in 2 steps: first, join to the first detail (ingredients) and aggregate the detail (using group_concat to make one single row of all related ingredient rows), then join that result to the second detail (ratings) and aggregate again.

In the example above, the ingredients are returned in a structured string, exactly like it appeared in your example. If you want to access the data inside PHP, you might consider adding a bit more syntax to make it a valid JSON string so you can decode it into an array using the php function `json_decode()`: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

To do that, simply change the line to:

```
CONCAT(
    '['
,   GROUP_CONCAT(
        '{"ingredient":', c.ingredient
    ,   ',"ingAmount":', c.ingAmount, '}'
    )
,   ']'
)
```

(this assumes `ingredient` and `ingAmount` are numeric; if they are strings, you should double quote them, and escape any double quotes that appear within the string values)

The concatenation of ingredients with `GROUP_CONCAT` can lead to problems if you keep a default setting for the `group_concat_max_len` server variable. A trivial way to mitigate that problem is to set it to the maximum theoretical size of any result:

```
SET group_concat_max_len = @@max_allowed_packet;
```

You can either execute this once after you open the connection to mysql, and it will then be in effect for the duration of that session. Alternatively, if you have the super privilege, you can change the value across the board for the entire MySQL instance:

```
SET GLOBAL group_concat_max_len = @@max_allowed_packet;
```

You can also add a line to your my.cnf or my.ini to set group_concat_max_lenght to some arbitrary large enough static value. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len

Comment: wow thanks, about to do some testing with this. 2 things though, not familiar with concat at all...I see it looks like you formatted to my example of displaying "objects in an array" but wouldnt what u did  literally be a string? I need it to be an array. And second, is `SET @@group_concat_max_len = @@max_packet_size;` something i just run on my table as a query or what im not sure how to use that or "set" it

Comment: It's "GROUP_CONCAT". CONCAT just glues multiple strings together within one row, GROUP_CONCAT works like CONCAT but also glues strings across rows (aggregation). Will update the answer to address the other questions.

Comment: Thanks so much, seriously saved my project. 1 last thing though to make sure this whole solution works. I'm having trouble getting the JSON properly formatted to parse it on my end in AS3. I think im having trouble getting all the double quotes in the right place. could you look at what i updated above and see if you happen to have any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: wait a minute, why do you want to parse the json in as3 (whatever that is...)? I thought you needed the data in a PHP array. To do that, loop through the rows of the mysql resultset, and apply the php function json_decode() to the ingredients column. Regarding the quotes: in SQL you need single quotes to denote strings, and you can use double quotes verbatim. However, you'll need to take care to denote that entire thing as a proper PHP string. What quotes are you using to delimit the query string in PHP?

Comment: Oh, I just noticed an error in my directions. The previous example would generate a list of object literals as json. But a list is not valid Json, it was meant to be an array. So the list needs to be enclosed in [ and ]. Fixed in the answer.

Comment: No, that is not a typo. The intention of `GROUP_CONCAT()` is to make an aggregate of ingredient "objects", like so: `{"ingredient": 1, "ingrAmount": 2}, {"ingredient": 2, "ingrAmount": 1}` etc. So the aggregation is concatenation of strings across rows, and this yields a "forest" of objects. That "forest" is not valid json, so we use `CONCAT()` to create a leading `[` and a trailing `]` around it to get a valid JSON array.

Comment: awesome. thanks a lot! It's pretty great this can be done all in 1 query.

Answer (score 0):

One obvious solution is to actually perform two queries:

1) get the food

```
SELECT a.foodId, a.foodName, a.foodDescription, a.typeOfFood
FROM `foods` a
WHERE a.foodsId=4
```

2) get all of its ingredients

```
SELECT c.ingredient, c.ingAmount
FROM `foods_ing` c
WHERE c.foodsId=4
```

This approach has the advantage that you don't duplicate data from the "foods" table into the result. The disadvantage is that you have to perform two queries. Actually you have to perform one extra query for each "food", so if you want to have a listing of foods with all their ingredients, you would have to do a query for each of the food record.

Other solutions usually have many disadvantages, one of them is using [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function, but it has a tough limit on the length of the returned string.

Comment: The limitation of GROUP_CONCAT is merely annoying, not a real problem. If you set group_concat_max_len to max_packet_size, you will never run into the limit; that is, if you do, it won't be because of the limit of group_concat but because of the limit to the maximum size of the result as a whole.

Answer (score -1):

When you compare MySQL's aggregate functions and GROUP BY behavior to SQL standards, you have to conclude that they're simply broken.  You can do what you want in a single query, but instead of joining directly to the table of ratings, you need to join on a query that returns the results of the aggregate functions.  Something along these lines should work.

```
select a.foodId, a.foodName, a.foodDescription, a.typeOfFood, 
       c.ingredient, c.ingAmount,
       b.numRatings, b.avgRating
from foods a
left join (select foodId, count(foodId) numRatings, avg(foodRating) avgRating
           from foods_ratings
           group by foodId) b on a.foodId = b.foodId
left join foods_ing c on a.foodId = c.foodId
order by a.foodId
```

Comment: is the `b.avgRating` intentional? there is no "averageRating" column. Only a foodRating channel which i perform the `avg()` function on. to get the avRating. Should the food_ing be inside the extra select? rather than the rating code? I'm trying to get multiple ingredients for each food.

Comment: This query does not solve the problem, you still get multiple rows per food (namely, one for each ingredient)

Comment: @brybam: There *is* an avgRating column; I created it with the expression `avg(foodRating) avgRating` in the subquery. It makes sense to change the name, because "foodRating" and "the average of foodRatings" doesn't mean the same thing. "avgRating" better expresses the meaning of the column after taking its average.

Comment: @RolandBouman: The OP was getting only *one* ingredient per food. When you have multiple ingredients, you should store them in multiple rows (one row per ingredient), and so you should expect to retrieve multiple rows (at least one per ingredient). The expressed problem was to "display all the information plus all the ingredients in that food."